# how to show different image in div per the screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, jquery-plugins

So I am pretty new to this but I am wondering for a web page that has a big image in the middle like github:windows page, how would do you work with the image inside that div/area depending on the screen size? is there a way to get images to resize or be cut off depending on either window size or screen size? is it typical practice to use media queries to change the picture based on the device? How is this done in css (can I reselect src in css for the img tag)? do you have to use a window resize js event to continually re-check like masonry?

I know these are quite a few questions (sorry) but I am really just looking for advice on best practice approach as again I am new to this....

always appreciated!

Comment: do you mean something like this: `http://www.cssbakery.com/2011/11/size-and-crop-image-using-css.html`

Comment: this would have been the first accepted answer if I could have choosen it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/) may be what you are looking for. It offers dynamic resizing and caching of images based on screen size. It's very easy to implement and has very few dependencies.